# Can I have specify TLS configurations in a template?

Tags: ssl, rsyslog

I am trying to set this up for SIEM ingestion on RHEL 8. I have this configuration below, however, the normal non-tls TCP doesn't work.

I know the problem is because I have gtls globally and in my imtcp module - that is obvious, but what I cannot find is how to add this configuration into just a single input template that I can add to each need ruleset. Can that even be done?

I have tried adding the following into my input template to no avail. They seem deprecated.

I tried adding:

```
(1)
  StreamDriver.Name="gtls"
  StreamDriver.Mode="1"
  StreamDriver.Authmode="anon"

(2)
Tag="ssl"

(3)
tls="on" 
tls.caCert="/etc/rsyslog.d/certs/CA.pem" 
tls.myCert="/etc/rsyslog.d/certs/server.pem" 
tls.myPrivKey="/etc/rsyslog.d/certs/Key.key" 
tls.authmode="name"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
  
########## MODULES ##########
module(load="imudp")
module(load="imtcp" MaxSessions="500"
StreamDriver.Name="gtls"
StreamDriver.Mode="1"
StreamDriver.Authmode="anon"
)

########## TEMPLATES ##########
template(name="FileFormat" type="list") {
 property(name="rawmsg-after-pri")
 constant(value="\n")
}

# make gtls driver the default and set certificate files
global(
DefaultNetstreamDriver="gtls"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/etc/rsyslog.d/certs/CA.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/etc/rsyslog.d/certs/server.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/etc/rsyslog.d/certs/Key.key"
)




# semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p udp <port>
############### udp_input  ###############
input(type="imudp" port="8501" ruleset="udp_input")
template(name="udp_input" type="string" string="var/log/remote/udp_input/%HOSTNAME%/%$day%_%$hour%.log")
ruleset(name="udp_input"){
action(
 type="omfile"
 dirCreateMode="0755"
 template="FileFormat"
 dynafile="udp_input"
)
}

# semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp <port>
############### TCP_input  ###############
input(type="imtcp" port="8502" ruleset="TCP_input")
template(name="TCP_input" type="string" string="var/log/remote/TCP_input/%HOSTNAME%/%$day%_%$hour%.log")
ruleset(name="TCP_input"){
action(
 type="omfile"
 dirCreateMode="0755"
 template="FileFormat"
 dynafile="TCP_input"
)
}



# semanage port -a -t syslog_tls_port_t -p tcp <port>
############### tls_input  ###############
input(type="imtcp" port="8611" ruleset="tls_input")
template(name="tls_input" type="string" string="var/log/remote/tls_input/%HOSTNAME%/%$day%_%$hour%.log")
ruleset(name="tls_input"){
action(
 type="omfile"
 dirCreateMode="0755"
 template="FileFormat"
 dynafile="tls_input"
)
}
```

I have modules:
rsyslog.x86_64
rsyslog-gnutls.x86_64
rsyslog-gssapi.x86_64
rsyslog-relp.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Did you also tried to replace imtcp module via plain text TCP imptcp?

`############### TCP_input  ###############`

`input(type="imptcp" port="8502" ruleset="TCP_input")`